# RavenDB Map only index returns null values after AsProjection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, nosql, ravendb

I have a next index:

```
 public class TestIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Resource>
    {
        public class Result
        {
            public string Caption { get; set; }
            public string TestVal{ get; set; }
        }
        public TestIndex()
        {
            Map = resources => from r in resources
                               select new
                               {
                                   Caption = r.Caption,
                                   TestVal = r.Caption
                               };

        }
    }
```

And that's how I query it:

```
            var data = session.Query<Resource, TestIndex>()
                              .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults())
                              .AsProjection<TestIndex.Result>()
                              .ToList();
```

The problem is that after query TestVal property is null for each object, when Caption is filled with expected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a projection from the index, you need to store that value

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, query on the index still retruned null values. It turned out that i did to fast test - after each program running index was also runing and it had no enough time do biild up. In this case sulution is use customization.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow():

```
Query<ResultType,IndexType>()
.Customize(customization => customization.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow()) //this is imprtant when you using quick tests, not in production server
.Where(...).AsProjection<ResultType>
```

You also need remember about storing data from index to DB and use at the end in index class:

```
StoreAllFields(FieldStorage.Yes);
```